# How to use pandas plotting with subplots. ax=df.plot() or df.plot(ax=ax1). whats the difference

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have created two axes in a figure using matplotlib and tried to plot data. One method worked and one did not. My question: why did it not work and what's the difference between the two?

The one which didn't work:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,figsize=(15,6))
ax[0]=df['Global_Sales'].head(10).plot(kind='bar')
ax[0].set_xlabel('different games')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Sales')
ax[1]=df['Critic_Score'].head(10).plot(kind='bar')
ax[1].set_xlabel('different games')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Critic Score')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Here the first axes remains blank and the second axes gets overwritten**

The one which did work:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,figsize=(15,6))
df['Global_Sales'].head(10).plot(kind='bar',ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_xlabel('different games')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Sales')
df['Critic_Score'].head(10).plot(kind='bar',ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set_xlabel('different games')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Critic Score')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

showed both the graphs on both axes properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example did not produce the output you were expecting because you did not pass the axes objects that you generated using the `plt.subplots` call to the pandas `.plot` call. Your second example produced the output you were expecting becuase you did pass the axes objects that you generated using the `plt.subplots` call to the pandas `.plot` call.

In short, if you want a pandas `.plot` call to plot on a particular axis (say `ax1`), you need to pass that axis object into the `.plot` call as a keyword argument: `df.plot(ax=ax1)`